# Get maximum count based on number of colors

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array that looks like the following (I did a json_encode so it's easier to read on StackOverflow). I'm trying to get the highest color count based on number of colors. So for example single colors like Red has a count of 32 and White has a count of 31. Then I'd like to get the highest value which would be 32. And for dual colors I'd like to get back 4 since [White, Black] has the highest count among the dual colors. And for tri colors I'd like to get back 8 since they are all equal, etc.

```
[{
        "colors" : "",
        "count" : 55
    }, {
        "colors" : "[\"Red\"]",
        "count" : 32
    }, {
        "colors" : "[\"Green\"]",
        "count" : 32
    }, {
        "colors" : "[\"Blue\"]",
        "count" : 32
    }, {
        "colors" : "[\"White\"]",
        "count" : 31
    }, {
        "colors" : "[\"Black\"]",
        "count" : 31
    }, {
        "colors" : "[\"White\",\"Black\",\"Red\"]",
        "count" : 8
    }, {
        "colors" : "[\"Blue\",\"Red\",\"Green\"]",
        "count" : 8
    }, {
        "colors" : "[\"White\",\"Blue\",\"Red\"]",
        "count" : 8
    }, {
        "colors" : "[\"Blue\",\"Black\",\"Green\"]",
        "count" : 8
    }, {
        "colors" : "[\"White\",\"Black\",\"Green\"]",
        "count" : 8
    }, {
        "colors" : "[\"White\",\"Black\"]",
        "count" : 4
    }, {
        "colors" : "[\"Black\",\"Green\"]",
        "count" : 3
    }, {
        "colors" : "[\"White\",\"Red\"]",
        "count" : 3
    }, {
        "colors" : "[\"Blue\",\"Green\"]",
        "count" : 3
    }, {
        "colors" : "[\"Blue\",\"Red\"]",
        "count" : 3
    }
]
```

I'd like to retrieve these values in an array. The result would look like this:

```
$max_color_count = array(55, 32, 4, 8);
```

The 55 is from the one which has 0 colors, the 32 is from the single colors, the 4 is from dual colors, and the 8 is from tri colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with array.

```
$max_color_count = array(0, 0, 0, 0);
foreach($data as $k => $v)
{
  $colors_amount = count($v['colors']);
  $max_color_count[$colors_amount] = max($max_color_count[$colors_amount], $v['count']);
}
print_r($max_color_count);
```

This works with `$data = json_decode("JSON_YOU_HAVE_GIVEN");`

```
$max_color_count = array(0, 0, 0, 0);
foreach($data as $k => $v) 
{
    $colors_amount = count(json_decode($v->colors));
    $max_color_count[$colors_amount] = max($max_color_count[$colors_amount], $v->count);
}
print_r($max_color_count);
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to do. How does this part work? count($v['colors'])

Comment: I'm getting an error, "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: It is a synonym of `sizeof()`, it returns size of a given array. In this row, it returns amount of colors in `$v['colors']` array.

Comment: It is because script is created for an array since you said that you have an array, and you are trying to make it work with object =)

Comment: Hmm, I tried typecasting like this: foreach((array)$data as $k => $v) but I still get the same error?

Comment: Yep, it is because even if `$data` is an array now, `$v` is not. Wait a minute and i will make it work with objects =)

Comment: I added new code, it works perfectly with `$data` equal to `json_decode` of JSON you have given.

Comment: It had a bug were it would save the smallest value depending on order of the values given. I modified it like this to fix it. if($max_color_count[$colors_amount] < $v->count) {
                $max_color_count[$colors_amount] = $v->count;
            }

Comment: Wow, really sorry, I did such a stupid bug there. Sorry. I need to sleep for a while

Comment: No worries. Maybe update your answer in case someone else needs the answer?

Comment: I fixed the answer already. I am still using `max` function, but i changed operand =)